# How to install Qt5 X11 Extras module in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: software-installation, qt5

For my build on travis CI I need qt5 x11extras addon. I tried to add ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa but cmakes  find_package(Qt5X11Extras REQUIRED) still fails. Where the heck does ubuntu hide the qt stuff?

Comment: I guess you have a answer, can I understand the reason for still using 12.04, many packages are already outdated. It shouldnt happen that an update can compromise your system as some packages are very new from the update, and some very old from 12.04.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Are you sure you're talking about Ubuntu 12.04? Qt5 [doesn't seem to be available](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&section=all&arch=any&keywords=qt5&searchon=names) in Ubuntu 12.04.

If you're talking about Ubuntu 14.04 or later, I think the package you want is named `libqt5x11extras5-dev`. Check if it's installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5x11extras5-dev
```

---

UPDATE:

Qt X11 Extras was [introduced in Qt 5.1](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/whatsnew51.html#new-modules), but the [Ubuntu SDK team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-sdk-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) (ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa), provides only Qt 5.0 for Ubuntu 12.04. After an extensive search, I failed to find a PPA that you could use. IMHO, you're left with 2 options:

- Uninstall all Qt5 packages that you installed from PPA and install the latest Qt5 using the [Qt Installer](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/).
- Upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 (or later) and install `libqt5x11extras5-dev`.

---

UPDATE 2:

If you're still interested, there's new [PPAs by Stephan Binner](https://launchpad.net/~beineri) with recent Qt versions for Precise and Trusty. In order to not mess with Qt system packages, they're installed in `/opt` so you'll have to inform the correct path (`/opt/qtXX/include/QtX11Extras`) to your build tool.

Example: if you want x11extras from Qt 5.1, you could add the Qt 5.1.1 PPA:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt511
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install `qt-latest` and `qt51x11extras`:

```
sudo apt-get install qt-latest qt51x11extras
```

The include files for x11extras will be in `/opt/qt51/include/QtX11Extras`.

Comment: Yes 12.04. How can I get it with a ppa?

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r Answer updated.

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r Another update. Good news.

Comment: Huh how did you get back to this. I am exactly now working on this. :D https://github.com/ManuelSchneid3r/albert/blob/travis-test/.travis.yml

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r I've installed the latest Qt Creator from that PPA a couple of days ago, then today I've got a reputation notification when you accepted the answer... Perfect timing ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you compile Qt5 on your own, you need to clone the git submodule `qtx11extras`. If you then run configure and make, Qt will compile the extras, too.

Qt has a script named `init-repository` in order to control git submodules to be cloned, but did not initialized qtx11extras for me.

Comment: Interesting. Is this not part of the regular qt-tarball? I have compiled qt, including qtwebkit/engine, but QtX11 is indeed missing. I thought this was because of something missing in my local X11 installation but now I am not so sure after reaing that.